# How can i get the selected DateTimePicker Value to the Excel cell using C# in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Could some one suggest me the correct code for that.
I tried with :

```
Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value
```

But it doen't work.

Comment: what does mean "it doesn't work."?

Comment: ie. In the UI i select For eg: "1/20/2016" but it doesn't gets updated

Answer (score 2):

It returns `DateTime`, so you should convert it to `String` using `ToString()` method.

```
Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in this `ValueChanged` event of `DateTimePicker`:

```
private void DTPicker1_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.DTPicker1.Value;

}
```

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).